# Connecting Maru OS to Google account

Tags: google-account

I have just installed Maru OS on my Nexus 5. When, in phone mode, I attempt to add my google account (for email and calendar access) it prompts me for my email and password. On entering this, it says `username or password incorrect`.

Back on my laptop, I get an email from Google:

> Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your Google account xxxxxxxx@gmail.com, using an application such as an email client or mobile device. Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices:

The IP address shown for this access attempt is geolocated near me, but it not an IP address I recognise. It is not my external IP address. I have since changed my password.

Is it safe to connect Maru to Google accounts? If so, how is it done?